# What is MK Rank?

Tags: dungeonmans

I'm not too far into Dungeonmans yet, but when I hover over enemies I see their "MK Rank".

[image]

I initially thought it might effectively be the monster level, but I noticed when I hover over my brand spanking new level 1 character, it says I'm MK Rank 3.

What is MK Rank?

Answer (score 1):

MK stands for Monster Knowledge.  It represents the amount of information you know about that monster class.

In order to start accumulating MK, you need to retrieve a Priceless Artifact.  Bring it to the headmaster, turn in your relics, and agree to build a Museum.

From this point forward, you will receive some MK points every time you defeat a monster.  When you gain an MK level, a book of monster knowledge will drop.  Turn this in to the headmaster to pass your knowledge on to future dungeonmans.

One of the most useful pieces of information you can get from MK ranks is current HP and max HP.